# ObjC: Convert a decimal number to a base-26 string using the letters A-Z for digits

Tags: objective-c

I need to write an Objective-C function to convert a decimal integer to a base-26 string like below example. And also reverse it.

```
0 = A
1 = B
2 = C
...
25 = Z
26 = AA
27 = AB
28 = AC
```

etc.

Comment: can yiou show ur tried code

Comment: what will be ? = ABA

Comment: ABA is not next value it is a sample value.

Comment: Don't put negatives without reason and if you don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a recurcivefunction to do this

```
+ (NSString *)alphaValueForNum:(int)num {

    NSDictionary *charInfo = @{@"A": @0,
                               @"B": @1,
                               @"C": @2,
                               @"D": @3,
                               @"E": @4,
                               @"F": @5,
                               @"G": @6,
                               @"H": @7,
                               @"I": @8,
                               @"J": @9,
                               @"K": @10,
                               @"L": @11,
                               @"M": @12,
                               @"N": @13,
                               @"O": @14,
                               @"P": @15,
                               @"Q": @16,
                               @"R": @17,
                               @"S": @18,
                               @"T": @19,
                               @"U": @20,
                               @"V": @21,
                               @"W": @22,
                               @"X": @23,
                               @"Y": @24,
                               @"Z": @25};


    NSString *letter =  [[charInfo allKeysForObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(num % 26)]] lastObject]; //  ((num % 26));
    int remain = floor(num/26);
    return  (remain > 0) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[self alphaValueForNum:(remain-1)],letter] : letter;

}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient implementation. 1) There is no reason to use recursion. 2) There is no need for a dictionary.

Comment: Your answer also only solves half of the question. This makes no attempt to go back from base-26 to decimal.

Comment: @rmaddy: Ok then can you please give me the correct function. I can update it.

Answer (score 1):

seems that you want to create a number with a base of 26. So its no different to bit numbers with base 2 or decimals with base 10. But your model lacks of missing 0

each digit has a power base, from right to left. In bits its:

```
2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0

  1   0   1   1
```

Now mulitply the bit with the power and sum all values:

```
2^3=8x1=8

2^2=4x0=0

2^1=2x1=2

2^0=1x1=1
```

So the value of 1011 in decimal is 11.

Same with your base(assume a=0, z=25)

```
26^2 26^1 26^0

   b    z    z

26^2=676*b(1) =676

26^1=26 *z(25)=650

26^0=1  *z(25)=25
```

So the value of bzz = 1351

Now you have the basics and should be able to create your method ;-)